# Why do i get undeclared identifier error when i add the curl code i need for http requests

Tags: winforms, curl, c++-cli

I am trying to make an application in windows forms using c++
This code gives me error c2065 (indeclared identifier 'string')(line 129) and error c2146 (missing ';' before identifier 'param')(line 129)
+ 3 c2065 errors telling me about 'param' and 'cout' is undeclared.
I am quite new to c++, so it could possibly just be me doing something that c++ does not allow me to do. In that case i would be happy if someone told me what i did wrong so i could avoid doing that.

```
#pragma once
#include "curl/curl.h"

namespace Project1 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for skapaKonto
/// </summary>
public ref class skapaKonto : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode ret;

    skapaKonto(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        curl = curl_easy_init();
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~skapaKonto()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip^  contextMenuStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->contextMenuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip(this->components));
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(60, 78);
        this->textBox1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(328, 22);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // contextMenuStrip1
        // 
        this->contextMenuStrip1->ImageScalingSize = System::Drawing::Size(20, 20);
        this->contextMenuStrip1->Name = L"contextMenuStrip1";
        this->contextMenuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(61, 4);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(60, 110);
        this->textBox2->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->PasswordChar = '*';
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(328, 22);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(137, 142);
        this->button1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(187, 62);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button1->Text = L"Skapa";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &skapaKonto::button1_Click);
        // 
        // skapaKonto
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(464, 286);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this->Name = L"skapaKonto";
        this->Text = L"skapaKonto";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
  #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    if (curl) {

        const char* url = "10.130.216.101/TP/Admin/funktioner/skapa.php";

        string param = "nyckel=iRxOUsizwhoXddb4&funktion=skapaAKonto&anamn=BJORN&tjanst=47&rollid=6";
        const char *data = param.c_str();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);


        ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (ret != CURLE_OK)
            cout << "bad request";


    }
}
};
}
```

THIS is when the code last worked (before i added curl code):

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for skapaKonto
/// </summary>
public ref class skapaKonto : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    skapaKonto(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~skapaKonto()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip^  contextMenuStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->contextMenuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip(this->components));
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(45, 63);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(247, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // contextMenuStrip1
        // 
        this->contextMenuStrip1->Name = L"contextMenuStrip1";
        this->contextMenuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(61, 4);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(45, 89);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->PasswordChar = '*';
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(247, 20);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(103, 115);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(140, 50);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button1->Text = L"Skapa";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // skapaKonto
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(348, 232);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Name = L"skapaKonto";
        this->Text = L"skapaKonto";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
 #pragma endregion
};
}
```

it should be mentioned that this curl code works on it's own, in a different header file.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This is not C#. It is C++/CLI. And agh that ruined my dupehammer :(

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Yes, my bad. Rolled it back now.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica that fixed some of the errors, is there a similar one with cout?

Comment: Yes, do some research and you'll find the answer quickly. I'm not going to tell you the header for every standard library feature you use one at a time

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica thank you, changed it to console::write, all is solved now.

Comment: Okay that works too

Comment: i forgot to say so but i solved it in the end, i don't remember exactly what i did but it was something stupid

Comment: maybe i don't have to say anything about my old questions